# Magento website popup from a observer

Tags: magento, popup, observers

I have an observer listening to the `controller_action_predispatch` event. This is because I'm doing some geo ip related logic for each page customers are visiting. 
I want to show a light-box popup to get customer's input as a part of the logic.

Part of the issue that I'm facing here is at this stage layouts are not loaded. :(

Is this possible to do? If so whats the best efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had to go with a different event to access the layouts from my Observer. Best one for me was listening to `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` event. Then I grab a block,

```
$myblock = $observer->getLayout()->getblock('myblock');
$myblock->setMyvar('PassMyValue');
```

And then use that value to popup my light box to get the user input.

Answer (score 1):

Look at

`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::renderLayout()`

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_layout_render_before');
Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_layout_render_before_'.$this->getFullActionName());
```

That event might work better

Comment: Thanx for make me think of a different event